# Can't install ionic2 SQLite plugin

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I work on Window, with MINGW64 bash. I create an Ionic 2 project and add the SQLite plugin with the following line :

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
```

When I run my project, with :
$ ionic serve --lab

My project start and is displayed on Firefox, but in my console I have the following line :

```
Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but it's not installed.    main.js
Install the SQLite plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage' main.js
```

But I don't have a "main.js" file in my project, I have only a main.ts file which contain :

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Does the plugins can be run on the emulate device on the web browser ?

Comment: This will be helpful: [docs](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#installing)

Comment: @kcp but in this sample its for Ionic1, not Ionic2, isn't it ?

Comment: you are probably missing `--save`. Try `ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save`

Comment: Also the cordova plugins work in device or emulator and not in `ionic serve`

Comment: But the plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation work in ionic serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins don't get loaded in ionic serve as @suraj pointed out. Try running it in the browser platform.

> ionic platform add browser
>
> ionic run browser

Comment: Like Suraj and n00b say some cordova plugins don't work. Maybe in the futur but not now in february 2017